# TDD Naïve Text Search Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, unit-testing, tdd

I need to test drive Naïve string search algorithm.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Can someone shed some light on how I could approach the issue.

should my tests only be testing outside behaviour? (i.e. the pattern occuring indexes irrespective of the algorithm used? )

Or should I be algorithm specific and test drive algorithm specific implementations?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_box_testing . Everyday apps change way too fast to do proper white-box testing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or should I be algorithm specific and test drive algorithm specific implementations?

This largely depends on how your class will be used. Testing public contract is usually the way to go (and it's fairly easy to write decent tests for that), so unless your clients can somehow *use* implementation details knowledge, I'd stick to that.

Note that having specific algorithm on paper could help pinpointing few basic tests, without writing strictly implementation related tests, like:

- invalid input (empty strings, nulls)
- input being too large/too small (like, pattern exceeding searched string length - what do you do then?)
- valid input, yet matching nothing

This should give you basic entry point for more implementation specific testing. Keep in mind that utilizing  [data driven testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-driven_testing) can help you avoid the need of having implementation level knowledge altogether, and with large enough data set might be just enough to verify algorithm correctness aswell.